# Pasar id a ventana modal jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

estoy haciendo un sistema en Java usando JSP. He programado la tabla en donde me muestra todos los usuarios con los botones de acciones (cambiar password, editar y eliminar) que invocan a un modal. Esto funciona, pero no se como hacer para pasar el **user** como parámetro al formulario del modal.
Adjunto el código de mi botón y del modal.

```
    <%
    for(Usuario u : listaUsers){%>
        <tr class="w3-hover-light-green">
          ....

          <td><button class="w3-xlarge fas fa-user-times w3-button w3-hover-indigo w3-text-red w3-round-xxlarge" onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='block'"></button></td>
     </tr>
    <%}%>
```

Y el modal de eliminar es este

```
<!-- Modal de la baja -->
            <div id="id04" class="w3-modal w3-round-xlarge">
                <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-card-4">
                    <header class="w3-container w3-indigo"> 
                        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
                        <h2 class="w3-center"> Eliminar Usuario </h2>
                    </header>
                    <form action="Usuario" method="post">
                        <div class="w3-container">
                            <div class="w3-row w3-section">
                                <p>Desea eliminar al usuario: IRIA EÑ USUARIO</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w3-row w3-section">
                                <div class="w3-half w3-center">
                                    <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-round-large" name="evento_eliminar">Eliminar</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="w3-rest w3-center">
                                    <a href="index.jsp" class="w3-button w3-red w3-round-large">Volver</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- FIN MODAL MODIFICA USUARIO -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realice una posible solución, no se si es óptimo o no.
En el botón del HTML iría esto:

```
<button class="w3-xlarge fas fa-unlock w3-button w3-hover-indigo w3-text-yellow w3-round-xxlarge" onclick="abroModal('id02','<%=u.getUsuario()%>')"></button>
```

En el script iría esto

```
function abroModalProducto(id, producto){
if(id === 'id02'){
    document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'; 
    document.getElementById("updateprod").value = producto;
}
if(id === 'id03'){
    document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'; 
    document.getElementById("deleteprod").value = producto;
}
```

}

Y en el modal iría esto:

```
<form action="../Producto" name="Producto" method="post">
    <div class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-row w3-section">
            <div class="w3-col" style="width:25%"><p>Desea eliminar el Producto: </p></div>
            <div class="w3-rest">
                <input id="deleteprod" class="w3-input w3-border" name="codigo" type="text" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-row w3-section">
            <div class="w3-half w3-center">
                <button class="w3-button w3-green w3-round-large" name="evento_eliminar">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-rest w3-center">
                <a href="../views/productos.jsp" class="w3-button w3-red w3-round-large">Volver</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Por lo menos funciona para todos las opciones